# Using array in WP User Query

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, parameter-passing

for a past two days I'm trying to make a custom search form for my Wordpress site, but I can not find a way to deal with wp_user_query function. I'm trying to use an array to search another array.

This is my form where I save data to database

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="121">  
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="122">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="123">  
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="124">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

*Value* represents skills ID

After submitting...

```
$skills = $_POST['check_list'];
add_user_meta( $userID, 'user_skills', $skills);
```

So now we have an array in user_skills metafield witch looks like this

```
s:48:"a:3:{i:0;s:3:"121";i:1;s:3:"122";i:2;s:3:"123";}";
```

In the other form you can choose from all available skills

```
<input type="checkbox" name="search_list[]" value="121">
<input type="checkbox" name="search_list[]" value="122">  
<input type="checkbox" name="search_list[]" value="123">  
<input type="checkbox" name="search_list[]" value="124">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

After submitting this form this happens.

```
$skills =$_POST['search_list'];

$ids = filter_var_array($skills,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

$args = array(   
              'meta_key' => 'user_skills',
              'meta_value' =>  $ids,
              'meta_compare' => 'IN'  
              );

$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);

foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
       echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';

    }
```

I've also tried this aproach, but it doesnt work

```
$args = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
             'relation' => 'OR', 
             array(
                 'key'   => 'user_skills',
                 'value' =>  $ids,
                 'compare' => 'IN',
             ),
        ),
    );
```

At this point I know that there are 3 users witch meets search criteria, but function does not return anything.

By using `print_r`I can see that function sees the array, but it does not work like I need to

```
[meta_value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 121
                    [1] => 122
                    [2] => 123

                )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think inside `WP_User_Query` builds a sql-query and then exec it. So you can't do search by column content using `IN` operator for. Because the final query will looks something like

```
SELECT * FROM users_meta WHERE user_id = 1 AND meta_key = 'user_skills' AND meta_value IN (121,122,123)
```

For example, if you use latest MySQL which support JSON search. You may save `user_skills` as json. And then search in it using [json search functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks for the insight, But operator IN is the only one that can use if i'm using an array(i think), this is a quote from wordpress codex "meta_value (string|array) - Custom field value (Note: Array support is limited to a compare value of 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN', 'EXISTS' or 'NOT EXISTS')" I will look into JSON solution later

Comment: But you may convert your array to json string using `json_encode()` function.